# Wolfram language from batch or py

Tags: scripting, automation, raspberry-pi

I would like to automate the commands in this website into a batch file, so when the batch file it runs these commands in sequence. http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/157461

Do any of you have any ideas. I know that you can just type in wolfram in a batch file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wolfram
```

It will give you this output:

```
Wolfram Language (Raspberry Pi Pilot Release)
Copyright 1988-2013 Wolfram Research
Information & help: wolfram.com/raspi

In[1]:=
```

How would you enter commands in the In[1]:= from a batch script?

Thanks in advance.
Ahmad

EDIT
I think this could help from http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RaspberryPi.html

```
wolfram -script file.wl
```

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html I've always used `.m` extension for mathematica scripts, `.wl` is new to me.

Comment: nice, i'll try it out now

Comment: Have you tried this `wolfram -script file.wl` line that you suggest yourself?

Comment: @shrx This is for the new version of Mathematica on the Raspberry Pi where many things with Mathematica-related names are renamed to match the new Wolfram Language name.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to format commands in the file, e.g. if I wanted 1+1, what would I do. I have tried just putting 1+1 and saving the file as test.wl, but nothing is output in the command window. BTW, this is for the PI.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2eoefn

Comment: You write your code exactly the same as you would in a mathematica notebook, except nothing will be printed to stdout if you don't wrap it in `Print[]` explicitly. Edit: see my answer for a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you very much, sounds obvious, but missed it completely

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a minimal example on how to run a mathematica script on a raspberry pi.
Create a simple script (I used my bash terminal to do it):

```
echo "sum=1+1; Print[sum]" > test.wl
```

Excecute the script:

```
wolfram -script test.wl
```

> 2